# How to organise User login methods in RESTful API using Web Api

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to understand how to correctly implement a RESTful API in my asp.net site using Web Api.
In this site users can login in a variety of ways. e.g email, username,facebook, twitter.

Using the RPC method, I would normally have API methods like loginByEmail(email, password)  or loginByUsername(username, password) etc

What would be the RESTful way of implementing this in my AP

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following endpoint:

```
POST /auth/login

{
   email: "johndoe@mail.com",
   password: "123456"
}
```

A response will look like:

```
{
    token: "jahsduqguwydVYTasbdvjabs_ahjsd",
    expires: 60000 // time in ms
}
```